# BPMN - Wait for an event once

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am having trouble modeling one particular use case.

- Task 1 and Task 2 are spawned in parallel.
- Task 1 is repeated multiple times based on a condition.
- Once the first Task 1 is completed, we must wait for Task 2 completion before continuing. Which means first iteration of Task 1 will wait (if Task 2 isn't yet complete), but subsequent iterations will continue since Task 2 is already completed.

Here is my try at modeling:

[image]

The issues I see with this model:

1- If Task 2 is completed before the first Task 1 is completed, the Event will be thrown, but not catched. And once Task 1 is complete, it will wait for event indefinitely.

2- On iterations 2+ of Task 1, it will wait indefinitely for the event as it is thrown only once.

Any help on how to model this would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use message event. Use conditional event. 
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/events/conditional-events/

FYI: I am not familiar with camunda because I am using JBPM. However, for your case it is clear you have to use conditional event.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up conditional event. I'll dig on the subject, but it seems a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

First off, message events are not suitable for notifying within the same pool. Use signal events instead.

Without understanding the real semantics of task 1 & 2 it is difficult to give a good answer. I'd suggest to unroll the loop and have the first occurrence of task 1 concurrently with task 2, then synchronize with a join and then loop over remaining task 1s.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought message was within a single process instance, and signal was across all process instances.

Comment: What is depicted here is simplified, as the real model repeats multiple tasks, not just Task 1. So unrolling the first iteration as different tasks would make too much duplication and would be hard to maintain.